# Align LinearLayout to bottom, under ViewPager that fills screen

Tags: android, layout

How can I create layout like this properly?

[image]

I want LinearLayout 2 under ViewPager (not inside).

I know there are few ways to archieve this, but what is the best way?

Comment: have you tried RelativeLayout as root view of this design?. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must set layout_weight your viewpager. You can use this xml copy paste.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>

    <ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this `Align LinearLayout to bottom`? Use `RelativeLayout` instead

Comment: @Xcihnegn yes. Layout_weight stretch to view_pager bottom and top.

Comment: @Xcihnegn my answer is correct. LinearLayout orientation is vertical and viewpager height is 0dp and viewpager layout_weight is 1. Please  can you try my  xml code in your project?

Comment: Yes the stretch could make bottom `LinearLayout` go out of screen without align

Answer (score 4):

Put all your controls in `RelativeLayout` control

use this in `ViewPager` control with this attribute

```
android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout2"
```

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on LinearLayout 2.

Comment: It is to be noted that you have to place the view pager below the linear layouts in the xml

Comment: below the first linearlayout and above the second one

Comment: No. The id injection will not work. Despite the fact that the position in the relative layout is just affecting the Z-order of the elements not the positioning on the x or y axis

Comment: @throws_exceptions_at_you Look better. Fahim is using the **anticipated id referencing** (`@+id`), instead of the **normal id referencing** (`@id`). With this (**horrible**) method, it will work as well. But I always use the **normal** way (**declare the ids before referencing** them).

Comment: Learned something new here @Der Golem.
I've just checked and it is as you say.

Comment: I have checked this again. And it gives me the anticipated error : Error:(13, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/et_searchbar').